# Remove trailing zeros from a decimal column

Tags: sql, db2

How can I remove the trailing zero from the below table using SQL:

```
SKU     SIZE
ABC     35.000000
QWE     36.000000
RTY     37.000000
VGY     38.000000
```

Expected results:

```
SKU     SIZE
ABC     35
QWE     36
RTY     37
VGY     38
```

Comment: CAST(column AS INT) => 35 CAST(column AS DECIMAL(10,2)) => 35.00

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In sql server cast the column containing decimal values to Int

```
Select SKU,CAST (Size AS INT) 
From tablename
```

For MySql use integer division function [DIV](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/arithmetic-functions.html#operator_div)

```
SELECT SKU,Size DIV 1
From Tablename
```

Comment: Error msg:- Error: SQL0104 - Token CAST was not valid.

Comment: Pls ignore the earlier comment. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest

```
SELECT sku, int(size)
FROM tablename
```

It's less typing.  ;-)